# "Save contact and add contribution" button in the contact form

Tags: contacts, contributions

In the contact form, I need to add a new button "Save and add Contribution" that, when pressed:

- save the current contact data
- redirect to the "New contribution" page, possibly with the contact already selected

How can obtain this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by writing some custom code in an extension. You can use a hook to insert this butoon on the contact form which does what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The way suggested by Jaap is correct. After creating a new extension in the buildForm hook I've inserted the following button:

> $form->add('submit', 'SaveAndContribution', ts('Save and Add
>   Contribution'));

and his template. The form is now complete.

At the moment, anyway, I'm not able to distinguish which button was pressed. I had a look at the postProcess hook, but without result.